# Changing active class of other division using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

So far I have written this code -

```
<div class="yearly-archive">
    <p> YEAR -  <span class="archive-year year-active"> 2014 </span> / 
        <span class="archive-year"> 2013 </span> /
        <span class="archive-year"> 2012 </span> /
        <span class="archive-year"> 2011 </span> /
        <span class="archive-year"> 2010 </span>
    </p>
</div>

<div class="news-container news-active" id="news-2014"></div>

<div class="news-container" id="news-2013"></div>

<div class="news-container" id="news-2012"></div>

<div class="news-container" id="news-2011"></div>

<script>
$('.archive-year').click(function() {
    $('.archive-year').removeClass('year-active');
    $(this).addClass('year-active');
});
</script>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/codestor/C7xj6/2/

I am trying to implement the following feature:

When I click on 2013, the **news-active** of **news-container** should switch to division with id **news-2013**

Help needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do almost the same thing as you did for the links...  Get the text from the clicked link and use that to build your id selector.  Since you have which link was clicked on you want to grab the text inside the link with `$(this).text()` then you want to make sure that you removed any extra space around the text with `.trim()`.  Now you can target the news div by concatinating the string with `'#news-1' + <link text value>`  Try...

```
$('.archive-year').click(function() {
  $('.archive-year').removeClass('year-active');
  $(this).addClass('year-active');
  $(".news-container").removeClass("news-active");
  $("#news-" + $(this).text().trim()).addClass("news-active");
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/C7xj6/3/)

Comment: Thank you. This does the job. I was almost there, I just needed that last line. Can you please edit your answer and explain the last line in detail. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 1):

Read the clicked span text using `$(this).text()` and then add class to its relative div like this:

```
$('.archive-year').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.archive-year').removeClass('year-active'); // remove class from all span
        $(this).addClass('year-active'); //add to current clicked
        $(".news-container").removeClass("news-active"); // remove class from all div

        $('#news-'+$.trim($(this).text())).addClass("news-active"); // add to current relative div
    });
```

All the trick is here : `$('#news-'+$.trim($(this).text())).addClass("news-active");` read the span text, trim it and concatenate with id **news-** part and add `news-active` class to it.

[**UPDATED FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/45eds/)

Answer (score 0):

```
   $(document).on('click', function(event){
        if($(event.target).hasClass('archive-year') && $(event.target).text() == ' 2013 '){
            $(div[class='news-container news-active']).attr('id', 'news-2013');
        }
    })
```

Comment: When you answer a question with code, it is a good idea to provide an explanation of what the code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$(function(){
  $('.archive-year').click(function() {
     $('.year-active').removeClass('year-active');
     $('.news-active').removeClass('news-active');
     $(this).addClass('year-active');
     $('.news-container[id*="'+ $.trim(this.textContent) +'"]').addClass('news-active');
  });
});
```